# Running Weston in a Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04, egl, wayland

I am currently trying to run a instance of Weston within a Docker container.

My system is an Ubuntu 16.04, currently running native Weston with DRI backend (I don't want any X11 dependency). So for starters I would like to run another Weston instance (with Weston as backend) within a Docker container.

Afterwards (my real goal) I would like to run a plain Ubuntu machine without any desktop environment, only graphics drivers installed and then a Weston Docker instance that has access to DRI, although I am not even sure if (and how) this would be possible.

So far I wrote a Dockerfile that inherits from Ubuntu, installs Weston and then runs Weston. The error message I received was "please run Weston in a virtual terminal". I added a call to openvt:

```
RUN openvt -- launch-weston
```

This command is run as root. However, I always receive the error

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.
```

Now I am kind of stuck since the available resources on the internet on this topic are very rare :)

Has anybody an idea of how I could proceed? Any additional technical information about running a DRI/GBM/DRM/KMS graphics application within a Docker container would help me a lot.

Comment: Shame you want to avoid X11, otherwise [Jessie Frazelle runs desktop apps in containers](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/).

Comment: Yes, thanks for your link. I already knew about his tutorials. But I really want to avoid X11 and finally do the Wayland stuff autonomously :)

Comment: Seems like I could simply add DRI Interfaces via  
--device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 \
--device=/dev/dri/card0:/dev/dri/card0 \
--device=/dev/dri/controlD64:/dev/dri/controlD64 \
--device=/dev/dri/renderD128:/dev/dri/renderD128

Comment: Note that `RUN` is executed during container build time - not sure you intend to do that ;-)